# Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am getting error while creating a functional component which return a svg. what is going on here?
here is the code :

```
import React from 'react';

const TwitterIcon = () => {
  return (
    <svg viewBox="328 355 335 276" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 630, 425A 195, 195 0 0 1 331, 600A 142, 142 0 0 0 428, 570A  70,  70 0 0 1 370, 523 A  70,  70 0 0 0 401, 521A  70,  70 0 0 1 344, 455 A  70,  70 0 0 0 372, 460A  70,  70 0 0 1 354, 370A 195, 195 0 0 0 495, 442A  67,  67 0 0 1 611, 380 A 117, 117 0 0 0 654, 363A  65,  65 0 0 1 623, 401A 117, 117 0 0 0 662, 390A  65,  65 0 0 1 630, 425Z"
      style= {styles.fill}/>
  </svg>
  );
}

    const styles = {
  fill: "fill: skyblue"
}

export default TwitterIcon;
```

Basically I want to use svg as a component .
If this is not solvable please let me know alternate way of using svg in react . I am Newbie

Comment: @ sriram can you check this is what you expecting and what color you want to fill let me know ! https://codesandbox.io/s/59531561-so-w61t7

Comment: its working can you update the answer

Comment: so I can accept it

Comment: added the answer you can accept it and upvote if it helped you, thanks sriram :)

Comment: ok one more how to reduce the size of the icon its too big

Comment: you can add width and height ,i have updated the codesandbox you can check it https://codesandbox.io/s/59531561-so-w61t7, let me know if it worked for you

Comment: yeah it works can i add that as css in js styles property ?

Comment: yes and you can use as style.width and style.height

Comment: please edit it in codesandbox I am newbie to coding

Comment: updated the answer with all required in comments :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes) property in the svg element as shown below,

```
import React from "react";

const TwitterIcon = () => {
  const { fill, width, height } = styles;
  return (
    <svg
      viewBox="328 355 335 276"
      height={height}
      width={width}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      fill={fill}
    >
      <path d="M 630, 425A 195, 195 0 0 1 331, 600A 142, 142 0 0 0 428, 570A  70,  70 0 0 1 370, 523 A  70,  70 0 0 0 401, 521A  70,  70 0 0 1 344, 455 A  70,  70 0 0 0 372, 460A  70,  70 0 0 1 354, 370A 195, 195 0 0 0 495, 442A  67,  67 0 0 1 611, 380 A 117, 117 0 0 0 654, 363A  65,  65 0 0 1 623, 401A 117, 117 0 0 0 662, 390A  65,  65 0 0 1 630, 425Z" />
    </svg>
  );
};

const styles = {
  fill: "grey",
  width: 210,
  height: 500
};
export default TwitterIcon;
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59531561-so-w61t7)

Answer (score 1):

What's `style="#3BA9EE"` is supposed to do? It's not the way you specify the styles. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/style

Do something like `<path ... style={{stroke-width: "2"}} />`

Comment: problem still exists Im using css in js

Comment: @sriramhegde I've edited my answer, see how it's done

Answer (score 1):

Style has to declare properties to which you assign values, I'm guessing you want to do something like `style="stroke: #3BA9EE"`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/style

Comment: yes I canged the code I am still getting the same error

Comment: What you've done will output `style="red"`, you need it to output `style="fill: red"`